# Flagging comments on mobile requires excessive scrolling

Tags: bug, comment-flags, mobile-web, flag-dialog

The mobile version of Stack Overflow does not allow you to flag comments. A simple workaround is to switch to the desktop ("full") site from the footer, then flag away (then usually switch back).

However, I have found that **sometimes,** you are required to **scroll down to the very bottom of the page before you can click Submit.** This is cumbersome, and causes you to lose track of where you were. It's particularly aggravating on a long page with many comments where you need to flag several - painstakingly find your way back, home in on the next comment you want to flag, (wait or pray that this took longer than five seconds! Grrr), click the flag icon again with the understanding that you will lose all this work and need to do it again in a few seconds.

Here's an example where the dialog is shown without the Submit button:

[image: Submit button out of reach]

The grey area above (and "behind") the dialog can be scrolled, but the dialog stays in place until you finally reach down to the bottom of the page:

[image: Finally displayed when you're at the bottom]

Could this be changed so the full dialog is visible when it is brought up?

IOS / iPhone SE / Safari

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171199/175248

Comment: @Makoto had this problem today even and when using the responsive method (the one the in the answer provided, which you linked) The flag option scrolls horizontally and doesn't scroll back leaving us unable to flag